# Has the python subprocess.Popen behaviour changed to print stderr always?

Tags: python

As per solutions here and python manual following code snippet must not print anything on screen, including stderr of the `cmd`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=tmpdir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
o, e = p.communicate()
```

But somehow I get the error messages of the `cmd` on terminal. Has the behaviour changed? I have tried following variant, and it has same results too:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=tmpdir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
o, e = p.communicate()
```

I have Python 2.7.5 on CentOs 7.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Particularly, what is `cmd`? And what, exactly, is the terminal output?

Comment: cmd is a tool I use at my workplace and it takes only one argument which is a file. I'm not sure naming it will be any more helpful. Let me try to find another command which is widely available that can be used in this example.

Comment: How about `['sh', '-c', 'echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; echo tty >/dev/tty']`?

Comment: ...as the output of the above will imply, it's almost certain your program writes direct to the TTY, not to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

No, it didn't change. Your assumptions are wrong. Make sure you're running the correct piece of code, or try to find out what other things could be writing to the terminal. Because running a subprocess with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` will redirect **all** stderr output to stdout.